# Dynamically add Primefaces Hotkey control

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am building an app where one of the requirements is heavy use of hotkeys.  So heavy in fact that we want to pull those hotkeys back into a central controller.

The basic idea is each page will have a key associated with it.  When jsf hits that key, it will go back to a central enummap to decide what hotkeys are supposed to be associated with that page and what methods are supposed to be added to the keys of that page.

My problem is the dynamic load.  I can't use the

For now, I have this

```
<h:form binding="#{hotkeyController.form}">
    <f:event listener="#{hotkeyController.genKeyHandler('HOTKETEST')}" type="preRenderComponent"/>

    <p:outputPanel id="displayHotkey">  
    <h:outputText value="#{hotkeyController.keyText}" rendered="#{not empty hotkeyController.keyText}"/>  
    </p:outputPanel> 
</h:form>
```

Then for my backing bean i have this

```
public void genKeyHandler(String pageKey) {
    Hotkey hotkey = new Hotkey();
    hotkey.setBind("ctl+shift+d");
    hotkey.setAsync(true);

    // "#{hotkeyController.keyHandler('HOTKETEST', 'F1')}"
    hotkey.setActionExpression(createMethodExpression("#{hotkeyController.keyHandler('HOTKEYEXAMPLE', 'CTLSHIFTD')}", null,
        String.class, String.class));
    hotkey.setUpdate("displayHotkey");
    form.getChildren().add(hotkey);

    hotkey = new Hotkey();
    hotkey.setBind("ctl+shift+a");
    hotkey.setAsync(true);

    // "#{hotkeyController.keyHandler('HOTKETEST', 'F1')}"
    hotkey.setActionExpression(createMethodExpression("#{hotkeyController.keyHandler('HOTKEYEXAMPLE', 'CTLSHIFTA')}", null,
        String.class, String.class));

    hotkey.setUpdate("displayHotkey");
    form.getChildren().add(hotkey);

}
```

Now this works in the sense that it actually inserts the hotkey into the form.  I can see it in inspector.  But, my problem is two fold.  One, if I refresh the page, I get duplicate ID errors, if I use the preRenderView, I get "Error restoring component" errors.  seems like no combination will work.

Is there any way to make this work?  All I want is to have the bean method that inserts the hotkeys fire the first time a page is loaded and only fired once in the life of the page/view/whatever.  This shouldn't be this hard.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that you use an exclusive form for the hotkeys.

Here is the sample:

```
<h:form id="mainForm">
    <p:remoteCommand name="loadHotKeys" action="#{hotkeyController.genKeyHandler('HOTKETEST')}" update=":hotkeyForm" global="false" process="@this" />
    <p:outputPanel id="displayHotkey">  
        <h:outputText value="#{hotkeyController.keyText}" rendered="#{not empty hotkeyController.keyText}"/>  
    </p:outputPanel> 
</h:form>

<h:form id="hotkeyForm" binding="#{hotkeyController.form}" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(loadForm());
</script>
```

And the genKeyHandler method should clear the hotkeyForm (`form.getChildren().clear()`) before adding the hotkeys.